# Formatting and Aligning the console output

Tags: python

I've a small python program which takes filename as the argument and it browses the given .txt file for a table when it finds it it prints the table on the console. But the table appears to be messy, how to control the output text format which appears on the console?

My program is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

filename=sys.argv[1]
filedir=os.getcwd()

string= 'RADIANS'
count=0
N=11
flag=0

f = open(path,'r')
if flag==0:
    print ('Scanning for FATAL errors---NONE')
    print('Scanning for SYSTEM FATAL errors---NONE')
    print('----------------------------------------Structure EigenFrequncies--------------------------------------------\n')
    newsearch = 'NUMBER OF ROOTS'
    for line in f:
        if newsearch in line:
            print line
            break
    print('------------------------------------- REAL EIGEN VALUES(Displaying first 10 modes)-------------------------------\n')
for line in f:
    if flag==0:
        if string in line:
            print line
            for i in range(N):
                if exitstring1 not in line:
                    line = f.next().strip()
                    print line
                else:
                    break
            break
f.close()
```

The text file is as follows:

```
                          E I G E N V A L U E  A N A L Y S I S   S U M M A R Y   (READ MODULE) 



                                     BLOCK SIZE USED ......................    7

                                     NUMBER OF DECOMPOSITIONS .............    3

                                     NUMBER OF ROOTS FOUND ................   46

                                     NUMBER OF SOLVES REQUIRED ............   33

1    EXTSE REDUCTION RUN                                                       JULY   1, 2014  NX NASTRAN  5/ 1/14   PAGE    10
      SE_10_KGH_09_5000HZ                                                                                                           
0                                                                                                                                   

                                              R E A L   E I G E N V A L U E S
                                         (BEFORE AUGMENTATION OF RESIDUAL VECTORS)
   MODE    EXTRACTION      EIGENVALUE            RADIANS             CYCLES            GENERALIZED         GENERALIZED
    NO.       ORDER                                                                       MASS              STIFFNESS
        1         1        1.858571E+08        1.363294E+04        2.169750E+03        1.000000E+00        1.858571E+08
        2         2        2.912237E+08        1.706528E+04        2.716023E+03        1.000000E+00        2.912237E+08
        3         3        4.555573E+08        2.134379E+04        3.396969E+03        1.000000E+00        4.555573E+08
        4         4        4.794632E+08        2.189665E+04        3.484960E+03        1.000000E+00        4.794632E+08
        5         5        4.850065E+08        2.202286E+04        3.505047E+03        1.000000E+00        4.850065E+08
        6         6        4.879794E+08        2.209025E+04        3.515773E+03        1.000000E+00        4.879794E+08
        7         7        4.898815E+08        2.213327E+04        3.522619E+03        1.000000E+00        4.898815E+08
        8         8        4.968964E+08        2.229117E+04        3.547750E+03        1.000000E+00        4.968964E+08
        9         9        5.004465E+08        2.237066E+04        3.560401E+03        1.000000E+00        5.004465E+08
       10        10        5.088724E+08        2.255820E+04        3.590249E+03        1.000000E+00        5.088724E+08
```

But when i run my code the output appears to be in this way:

```
 MODE    EXTRACTION      EIGENVALUE            RADIANS             CYCLES            GENERALIZED         GENERALIZED

NO.       ORDER                                                                       MASS              STIFFNESS
1         1        2.292081E+04        1.513962E+02        2.409545E+01        1.000000E+00        2.292081E+04
2         2        2.701519E+04        1.643630E+02        2.615918E+01        1.000000E+00        2.701519E+04
3         3        5.071461E+04        2.251991E+02        3.584154E+01        1.000000E+00        5.071461E+04
4         4        5.426810E+04        2.329551E+02        3.707596E+01        1.000000E+00        5.426810E+04
5         5        1.084471E+05        3.293130E+02        5.241179E+01        1.000000E+00        1.084471E+05
6         6        1.195545E+05        3.457666E+02        5.503046E+01        1.000000E+00        1.195545E+05
7         7        1.254440E+05        3.541807E+02        5.636961E+01        1.000000E+00        1.254440E+05
8         8        3.216040E+05        5.671014E+02        9.025700E+01        1.000000E+00        3.216040E+05
9         9        3.434422E+05        5.860394E+02        9.327106E+01        1.000000E+00        3.434422E+05
10        10        3.545295E+05        5.954238E+02        9.476464E+01        1.000000E+00        3.545295E+05
```

How can i control the alignment? can anyone help me with this?

Comment: use python `tabulate` module

Comment: i don't have root permissions to install that tabulate module, i work in a firm, Is there any other way to do it? @rjv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want your output to appear identical to that of the input table?

The problem is that you are stripping the data lines, but not the first heading line. For the data lines, stripping removes any trailing new line character(s), then `print` adds a new line to the output. For the first heading line, you are *not* stripping it, so when you print it you end up with 2 new lines (which is why there is a blank line in between the heading rows.)

Stripping also removes any leading white space, and this also affects alignment of the header and data lines.

To fix you can use `rstrip()` which will remove whitespace (including new lines) from the *end* of the line only.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

filename=sys.argv[1]
filedir=os.getcwd()

exitstring1 = "something that won't be found"
string= 'RADIANS'
count=0
N=11
flag=0

f = open(filename,'r')
if flag==0:
    print ('Scanning for FATAL errors---NONE')
    print('Scanning for SYSTEM FATAL errors---NONE')
    print('----------------------------------------Structure EigenFrequncies--------------------------------------------\n')
    newsearch = 'NUMBER OF ROOTS'
    for line in f:
        if newsearch in line:
            print line.rstrip()
            break
    print('------------------------------------- REAL EIGEN VALUES(Displaying first 10 modes)-------------------------------\n')
for line in f:
    if flag==0:
        if string in line:
            print line,
            for i in range(N):
                if exitstring1 not in line:
                    line = f.next().rstrip()
                    print line
                else:
                    break
            break
f.close()
```

Note that added a value for `exitstring1` as this was not defined in your code.

An alternative would be to use `sys.stdout.write(line)` instead of print, without stripping.